# How to install Visual Python?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, wine, python, cinnamon

I'm a Linux newbie but I'm determined to get my favorite applications on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. I just installed Cinnamon.

I'm trying to install Visual Python and it requires Python 2.7. I followed the instructions on the VPython site but the Wine application isn't extracting anything from the Python .msi file. From the first line

```
wine start /i python-2.7.5.amd64.msi /qn TARGETDIR=~/Python27 ALLUSERS=1
```

it says `fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.`

I created that Python27 directory so I know it exists and it's empty. I know Ubuntu already has Python 2.7 so I just tried running the VPython.exe file but it says `&quot;This program can only be installed on versions of Windows designed for the following processor architectures: x64.&quot;` My Toshiba satellite has a 64-bit processor.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

You have `Python 2.7` already installed (as it should be by default). Just run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-visual
sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev
```

Then try to run any `.py` script that need `python visual`. It should run without any issues. You don't need to use the `.msi` installer.

Comment: The python-visual package is version 5.12. It was released in 2009. The latest Visual Python is version 6.04 released 2013 March 02.

Comment: No, still it doesn't run.. it says "no module named visual"..even module "ivisual" was tried but in vain